# No suitable constructor exists to convert from char to string

Tags: string, visual-c++, create-directory

I have defined a `createdirectory(const stdStr& path)` in a class and I am accessing that function from another class using `Directory::CreateDirectory("C:\\Temp");`

I am getting an error on "C"\Temp" saying that "

```
no suitable constructor exists to convert from "const char [4]" to "std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t>>"
```

Comment: What is stdStr?  Post real code, all of it that's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `"C:\\Temp"` string is an array of `char`, but the function is using a string templated on `wchar`.  Personally, I avoid Unicode like the plague, but I think you need `L"C:\\Temp"` (note the preceding L).